# Rest assured testing - API request 401 bad request

Tags: java, rest, api, authentication, csrf

I have a problem with sending API request via postman or Java lib "io.restassured".
When I do the same action on UI the request returns correct response, but when I try the same thing via postman or java code I get:

> ## 401 Bad request
>
> Your browser sent an invalid
>   request.

The java code

```
       public static void main(String[] args) {

        String requestUrl = "exampleBaseUrl/app/reports/api/rest/v1/graphs?context=shipper&reports_type=freights";

 Response response = RestAssured.given().relaxedHTTPSValidation().header("x-csrf-token", "18ea65e740eb0ddddadf0ef435d92564").
            when().
            get(requestUrl);
    }
```

I assume something is wrong with the authentication, because in dev tools i can see a Get request for CSRF_token, and it looks like this:

the endpoint for the token:

```
/login?get_csrf_token
```

and for this request I get following response:

```
{"csrf_token":"18ea65e740eb0ddddadf0ef435d92564"}
```

I am not sure how to solve this, I have also tried to get the token via java code by sending a get request to the token's endpoint `/login?get_csrf_token`
and this one gets my a HTML response with empty username and password input.

Answer (score 1):

**Error 401** means your request isn't authorized.

For authorization, usually while logging in you are given a token, which you will have to keep in your cache/local-memory and whenever you communicate with the server you have to add that in your request header (for your own introduction to the server)

It seems like in your case you can get a token from `/login?get_csrf_token` after logging in. Note that you don't need authorization for a login service.

Now, after getting token from the server, how to add it as a request header?  [See REST Assured Documentation](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#authentication)

Comment: thanks for the explanation, gonna play with it tomorrow